# Way to avoid gazebo calling gettimeofday so much?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After having performance problems I ran sysprof along side gazebo and noticed that > 40% of the cpu resources being used up were for calls to `sys_clock_gettime()` via `gettimeofday()` via `gazebo::common::Time::GetWallTime()`

This seems unusual. Is this an indication that I've something mis-configured? Is there a way to mitigate this?

gazebo-1.2.6

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/298/way-to-avoid-gazebo-calling-gettimeofday-so-much?/) by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 283 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Should have googled first. It looks like it's a known and fixed problem in the yet unreleased Gazebo 1.3

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/48/changing-from-gettimeofday-to/diff

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0